# Counting in SQL

Tags: sql

AFDELING = DEPARTMENT. MEDLEM = MEMBER. I want to view the number of members of each department, showing the department name, but I can't seem to get it working. All I get is duplicates of Personnr.

```
SELECT AFDELING.afdnavn, MEDLEM.personnr, count(*)
FROM [dbo].[MEDLEM],[dbo].AFDELING
WHERE AFDELING.afdnr = MEDLEM.afdnr
GROUP BY AFDELING.afdnavn, MEDLEM.personnr
GO
```

Tables used:

```
AFDELING
Afdnr  (Primary Key)
Afdnavn
```

```
MEDLEM
Afdnr  (foreign key)
Personnr (foreign key)  (Primary key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  AFDELING.afdnavn
  , COUNT(MEDLEM.personnr)
FROM
  dbo.AFDELING JOIN
    dbo.MEDLEM ON AFDELING.afdnr = MEDLEM.afdnr
GROUP BY
  AFDELING.afdnavn
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your mistake is that you are grouping by `MEDLEM.personnr`. You need to group only by     `AFDELING.afdnavn` and do the `count`

```
select
    A.afdnavn,
    count(*) as number
from dbo.AFDELING as A
    inner join dbo.MEDLEM as M on M.afdnr = A.afdnr
group by A.afdnavn
```